# Adding rows to static table view programmatically in swift iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I create new rows programmatically? I am not sure how to do that. I am going to use insertrowatindexpath method it may work but I don't know how to create an index path.

Comment: Indeed. If you don't know the final layout until run time, make the table dynamic. More work, but also more control.

Comment: @matt What does "You use a normal table" mean? Do you mean there is no need for `tableView.dequeueReusableCell` and I can just instantiate a `UITableViewCell`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @matt Said,static table is static,you can not add or delete any row in a static table.
However,static row's height is changeable.You can set it's height to zero to workaround.

```
var showRow3 = false

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 3{
        return showRow3 ? 44 : 0
    }
    return 44
}
```

Comment: iOS complains if you do that (you get a warning in the console), see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29365730/433373

Comment: @NicolasMiari Can you post the warning message? I use this trick in my own project and no warning show up. And your link question is about autosizing tableview cell ,it's another area.

Comment: Really? It is quoted in the question I linked: "Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead."

Comment: Just a minor worry. If it gets the job done, and there is not a more elegant alternative, then...

Comment: I checked my code,and I change showRow3 in viewDidLoad,so I won't get this warning.Your link question is indeed  a good alternative.